# Rails router not working after 2 records in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, routes

I have groups and users models, through relation between them. When I create a group all routes except users/show and groups/show are not working and are giving me routing error

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=> "groups"} ^
```

this is really bugging me out because

1. groups controller is not even involved in any of other routes like /document/new
2. i actually have "show" action in groups controller

my code is below

```
class GroupsController < ApplicationController

before_filter :group_created?, only: [:new]

def new
    @group = Group.new
end

def create
    group = Group.new(name: params[:group][:name], owner: current_user.id)
    user = User.find(group.owner)
        if group.save
            group.users = [ user ]
            flash[:success] = 'Group successfully created!'
            redirect_to group
        else
            render 'new'
        end
end

def show
    @group = Group.find(params[:id])
    @group_users = @group.users
end

def edit

end

def delete

end

private

def group_created?
    if Group.where("owner = ?", current_user.id).any?
        flash[:error] = "Error: Can't own more than one group"
        redirect_to current_user
    else
    end
end

end
```

Routes

```
resources :folders
resources :documents, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
resources :users
resources :groups

match '/signup', to: 'users#new'
match '/signin',  to: 'sessions#new'
match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete
match '/folders', to: 'folders#index'
match '/download', to: 'documents#download'
```

Comment: Please post 'rake routes' output

Comment: I think that´s not the error, but you missed the root route.

Comment: i have root route, just didnt put it here, ill put rake routes as soon as Im home, thanks for reading my question

Comment: Do you have a show link without including the item to show?

Comment: Could you please be more specific around this, do you mean a link_to or just a 'link' in general. In case you are asking about my show action in GroupsController, its working fine

Comment: problem solved, had wrong path in my view, i had group_path instead of groups_path i needed, stupid of me because i though problem can't be in view, but because it is in 'layout', i was calling it everytime.